# What is the difference between "git merge origin/master" and "git merge master"

Tags: git

I had a problem while I was trying to synchronize my development branch with the master
and now I am trying to understand what happened. The main problem was that I tried two things
and each had a different outcome.

After checking out to my development branch, I used the command "git merge origin/master".
I got some git conflicts and I fixed them.
After a few minutes I tried to re-synchronize the branches by using the following commands:

```
1. git checkout master
2. git pull
3. git checkout dev_branch
4. git pull
5. git merge master
```

After using these commands, I got other git conflicts(on different files), but different from the previous ones.

Why did I get different conflicts? I have to mention, once again, that I re-synchronized the branches
after a very short period of time and I am pretty sure that the remote master didn't get any updates
in the meantime. Is there any difference between these 2 methods? If yes, what is it?

Comment: They are branch names. They can either refer to the same commit or different ones.

Comment: Before first and second merge you have pulled both branches, so in both code could have changed and new conflicts could appear.

Comment: I think this question and that duplicated question is not similar.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your local `origin/master` wasn't up to date.
One of the (expected) effects of `git pull` is to update `origin/master`.

---

You can confirm this by looking at the history of your local `dev_branch` :

If you look at the history of your branch (using git-kraken, or gitg, or gitk, or `git log --graph --oneline`), you should see two distincts merges :

```
  * (dev_branch) Merge branch 'master' into dev_branch   # <- merge2
  |\
  | * (master, origin/master) commit aaa                 # <- aaa
  | |
     ...
  |
  *  | Merge banch 'origin/master' into dev_branch       # <- merge1
  |\ /
  | * commit bbb                                         # <- bbb
  | |
     ...
```

`bbb` was the state of your local `origin/master` at your first merge, `aaa` is the state of master after your `git pull` (and it is probably be the same as `origin/master`).

Another possibility is that your local `master` branch is not the same as `origin/master`.